# Canvas in IE9 does not work if display:table is applied

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-9

The below does not work in IE9 if the canvas has display:table applied to it.

```
var canvas1 = $("#canvas1")[0];
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var background = $("#background")[0];
context1.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/1353/

Is this a known issue?  Are there any workarounds (other than using a different display).

Comment: On the other hand, why would you ever apply `display: table` to a `<canvas>`?

Comment: @minitech For positioning?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally

Comment: Since it’s a `<canvas>`, it has a fixed width; you can just give it `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto`.